# Do Changelings daydream?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, changeling

In episodes of *Voyager*, it's shown that both the EMH and Seven of Nine can, and  do, daydream.

I was wondering if anything in canon suggests that Changelings (or Vulcans for that matter) daydream. It seems like Vulcans would consider it illogical, and for whatever reason I can't picture Odo or another Changeling daydreaming.

Comment: They dream of changeling sheep.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, they probably can.

In Deep Space Nine *If Wishes Were Horses* there is a scene where Odo is daydreaming of having Quark in a holding cell, after which an imaginary Quark appears on one of the monitors in the security office.

> QUARK: [...] So, Odo, what have you conjured up during all this?
>   ODO: Me?
>   QUARK: I should have guessed. Nothing at all.
>   ODO: I've spent all my time chasing incarnations of the Prophets, long dead lovers, Gunji jackdaws, blizzards, trollops.
>   QUARK: As I always said, a man without any imagination. Come along, my dears. I'll show you what a fertile imagination can do.
>
> [Security office]
>
> ODO: Imagination, ha. Computer, run a level one personnel sweep of all pylons.
>   COMPUTER: Requested function will take approximately three minutes.
>   (Odo glances up at the security cell CCTV feed and sees)
>   QUARK [on monitor]: Let me out of here! Let me out of here! Get the Nagus on subspace. I want to talk to him and I mean now! I'm not spending another minute in this cell.
>   ODO: How did you get in there?
>   QUARK [on monitor]: How did I get in here? You put me in here!
>   ODO: I guess I did, didn't I?
>   QUARK [on monitor]: Yeah.
>   (And the cell is empty again)
>   ODO: No imagination, indeed. Ha!
>   <sub>http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/416.htm</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Do Vulcans daydream? They can.

> After being bonded together as a result of mating and subsequently separating, T'Pol and Charles Tucker III began to daydream about each other. - https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Daydream

Can a Changling? Not sure.

There doesn't appear to be any mention of it throughout the run of DS9. I searched through all the [transcripts](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/) that mention dreams and Odo is never mentioned to have one or comment on one. At one point Bashir tells him 'sweet dreams,' but I think that is just him using the expression, and not an indication that Odo actually dreams.

The closest thing is the dream-like state is the one he shares with Sisko, Garak, and Dax. In this case they are just reliving one of Odo's memories from an alternate perspective.